# Facebook PHP SDK notifications do not show up in Facebook ios notifications?

Tags: php, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a web based app that sometimes send notifications to users using the following:

```
$response = $facebook->api('/'.$userId.'/notifications', 'POST', array(
                           'template' => 'A template here',
                           'href' => 'link-here',
                           'access_token' => 'part1|part2'));
```

It works as expected and the users get the notification if browsing Facebook in a browser however the notification does not appear in the Facebook app on iphones or any mobile devices?

Why is this, have I missed a setting in the developer setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of [Notifications API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications/)-

> The logic is that, on web, if Canvas setting exists, we always show 'Canvas URL + href'. If not, we show nothing. In the **future** (not in this version), we will also use existing URL re-writing logic to support **mobile** canvas and native mobile apps. We also append some special tracking params (fb_source, notif_id, notif_t) to the target URL for developers to track at their side.

Since this API is already in beta, you should wait for the next release for the mobile thing, this isn't handled in current version.